# Using Thread to find minimum distance of 2 keys

Tags: java, multithreading

I have String keys with me in a list, from a Set of MainKey , i am trying to find the minimum distance using thread.
So for each key , i have to loop through the complete Set and log the distance.
Am i using the threads properly , because in the logs i see two thread are using the same keys.

```
  public void matchKeys() {
    // read all MAin keys from redis

    Set<String> allKeys = redisTemplate.keys("*");
    // get the failure keys list 
    final List<String> FailureList = new ArrayList<>();
    FailureList.add("samsung5210e");
    FailureList.add("lgSL50");

   // thread to find the minimum distacne of all failure keys from the MainKeys list 
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int Distance;

            for (String e : FailureList) {
                for (String s : allKeys) {
                    Distance = damerauLevenshteinDistancee(e), s);

                        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Distance is {0} for Key {1} and the failure Key is {2}", new Object[]{Distance, s, e});


                }
            }

        }
    };
    t.start();

}
```

Comment: It seems that you have your main thread and a sub-thread doing all the comparisons. Maybe try to start a new thread for each string you get from the failureList?

Comment: Also, you should not calculate distance with the same key you are using. (ie. "abc" with "abc"). Also, to reduce time consumed, you could add storage of calculated distances, so you don't have to do your operation twice.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, the distance calculation is costly and you are trying to multi-thread it, what you should do is something like the following:

```
for (String e : FailureList) {
    for (String s : allKeys) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int distance = damerauLevenshteinDistancee(e), s);
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Distance is {0} for Key {1} and the failure Key is {2}", new Object[]{Distance, s, e});
            }
        }
        t.start();
    }
}
```